# how to disable job-setup and job-cleanup task in hadoop-1.0.4

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my Java code, I want to remove these tasks because I thinks they waste too much time in my program.
I tried using XML file but it's not work:

```
 <property>
<name>mapreduce.job.committer.setup.cleanup.needed</name>
<value>false</value>
```

Please help me know how to do that with any way? I think 2 tasks is not necessary. Is it right??
Thanks all!

Comment: What have you put in your setup and cleanup methods? By default these methods have no content in the Mapper and Reducer classes so whatever is "wasting time" must be something you've written. If you want to be able to disable whatever you've written externally, you could make your own config checks in the setup and cleanup methods.

Comment: have you tried setting final to true so that this value is not overwritten elsewhere?
`<property>
<name>mapreduce.job.committer.setup.cleanup.needed</name>
<value>false</value>
<final>true</final>
</property>`

Beware of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2129 though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you aren't using/setting the property correctly in your mapred-config.xml.
You may try following 2 things:

**1)**
Override `OutputCommitter` class and *do nothing* in `setupJob` and `cleanupJob` methods.

```
public static class NoSetupCleanupOutputCommitter extends OutputCommitter {
    @Override
    public void setupJob(JobContext jobContext) { }
    @Override
    public void cleanupJob(JobContext jobContext) { }
}
```

And then set this up in your `run()`, like follows:

```
conf.setOutputCommitter(NoSetupCleanupOutputCommitter.class);
```

**2)** You may try setting the config right in your Java code as follows:

```
//either one of the following configs should do according to the hadoop's version:    
conf.setBoolean("mapred.committer.job.setup.cleanup.needed", false);
conf.setBoolean("mapreduce.job.committer.task.cleanup.needed", false);
```

Comment: Hi Amar, thanks for your reply
I had tried your solutions but i didn't work, The taks job_setup and job_cleanup also was added by jobtracker so it waste my program running time. My hadoop version is 1.0.4. It doesn't have conf.setOutputCommitter().
Do you have any other suggestion?